# Flutter - Exception upon load CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, indicator

I've got problem with loading Indicator on start of widget. In my case I have some data downloaded in initState asynchronously and then _loading is set on false by setState.

I want to dialog to manipulate showing and disappearing it with Navigator.

Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown building NotificationView(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#e97a5], _InheritedTheme], state: _NotificationStateView#5dbc7):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#e85f9]
  state: OverlayState#340b4(entries: [OverlayEntry#2f82c(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#2187c(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#50b38(opaque: false; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#a3933(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#3e2d8(opaque: false; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#7c2c7(opaque: false; maintainState: true)])
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: NotificationView
  dirty
  dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#e97a5], _InheritedTheme]
  state: _NotificationStateView#5dbc7
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  NotificationView lib/main.dart:51:38
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3896:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3911:6)
#2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1168:14)
#3      OverlayState.insertAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:344:5)
#4      OverlayRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:44:24)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method 'drive' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: drive<Color>(Instance of '_ChainedEvaluation<Color>')
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp lib/main.dart:14:10
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (3) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/animation/animations.dart': Failed assertion: line 376 pos 15: 'parent != null': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp lib/main.dart:14:10
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (4) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 1782 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  NotificationView lib/main.dart:51:38
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Init view

```
Widget _buildView(BuildContext context) {
    if (_loading) {
      return showIndicator(context);
    }

    return Container(....);
}
```

Indicator method

```
showIndicator (BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    child: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found the problem

```
showIndicator (BuildContext context) {
  return Dialog(
    child: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
  );
}
```

`showDialog` doesn't return a widget it returns a `Future<dynmaic>` so you should use `Dialog` or any other widget instead of using `showDialog`

Comment: Yes, I know it'll work that way but in my case better will be collect data in initState method. There is no way to do this in initState?

Comment: `void initState() {
    super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
  }` you can wait for build method to finish then execute the method

Comment: You can also use provider or bloc for better state management.

Comment: I have updated the answer check it out it should work